# Passing a list through a "find" function = error?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

I defined a function that allows me to find a specific character in a parameter and returns all subsequent characters. Example:

```
def function1(parameter1):
    variable1 = parameter1[parameter1.find("&"):]
    variable1 = variable1[1:]
    return variable1
```

This seems to execute without issue.  However, I am having a problem with my second function, which allows me to pass a list through the first function, compare, and return True or False

```
def function2(list, variable1):
    for parameter1 in list:
        parameter1 = function1(list)
        if variable1 == parameter1:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Then, I define my list and variable1 to for function2 and print:

```
list = ["abc&123", "def&456", "ghi&789"]
variable1 = "123"
print function2(list,variable1)
```

I cannot seem to figure out what I've been doing wrong.  Something seems to be off wither how I am passing through the list, resulting in errors regarding split or find (I've tried both), and/or my comparison of Variable1 and parameter1.  I'm sure there's a small issue here that I keep getting tripped up on, but for the life of me I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Note: don't name your variable `list` as you are shadowing builtin `list`, or better don't give your variables/functions names from [\[Python\]: Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html).

Comment: This was poor formatting on my part as far as the post goes.  In the actual code, I did not name my variable "list."  I tried to keep things as concise as possible before posting it here, as over the years I've found posts with code that was too specific to be difficult to translate to my specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing `list` and `parameter1`.

```
def function2(list, variable1):
    for parameter1 in list:
        parameter2 = function1(parameter1)
        if variable1 == parameter2:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Also, this function returns when the first item in `list` is checked. You can return `True` if one of items fits or `False` if nothing is fitting:

```
def function2(list, variable1):
    for parameter1 in list:
        parameter2 = function1(parameter1)
        if variable1 == parameter2:
            return True
    return False
```